# Edge included in all the minimum spanning tree if it is included in at least 2 minimum spanning tree

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

Is it true that if an edge is included in at least two different minimum spanning tree, then that particular edge is included in all minimum spanning tree? If so why?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $C_3$, the cycle on three vertices.  List all its MSTs.